# Get xy coordinates from latitude and longitude in OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to get the XY on layer but the values are wrong; the lat lon values are correct.

I need to convert lat/lon to xy values with OpenLayers 2.

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152408/openlayers-lat-lon-conversion

Comment: Can you add your code that gives wrong results to your question?